# Please, help me to understand parsing trees example from craftinginterpreters.com

Tags: compiler-construction, recursive-descent

I'm trying to build a C compiler from scratch. Googling took me to the https://craftinginterpreters.com/ site. There are a lot of explanations how source code parsers work in detail. I've reached ["Parsing expressions"](https://craftinginterpreters.com/parsing-expressions.html) chapter and stuck in this.
They offer that algorithm of creating parse tree (recursive descend)

```
Expr expression() {
    Expr left = equality();
    ...
}

Expr equality() {
    Expr left = comparison();
    ...
}

Expr comparison() {
    Expr left = term();
    ...
}

Expr term() {
    Expr left = factor();
    ...
}

Expr factor() {
    Expr left = unary();
    ...
}

Expr unary() {
    if (WeFoundToken('-')) {
        return Expr.Unary(prev(), unary());
    }
    return primary; // if there's no '-'
}
```

But what happens when we parse that simple expression: `1 * 2 - 3`
I cannot understand how that's going to be working because top-level `expression()` when called falls through all lower-precedence operators parsing functions to the lowest precedence `unary()` function which will iterate through tokens, find (`-`) and return it to us as a unary (`-`) operation (`-3`) expression
In that case, there will be no way to build a valid tree that would look like this:

```
   -
 *   3
1 2
```

That would be invalid without a root node:

```
 *  
1 2  (-3)
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `term()` rule cover the case of `<something> - 3` before you reach `unary()`?

Comment: @mathiasr.jessen as i understand it calls `factor()` which immediately calls `unary()` as the first operation without extra logic. Then `unary()` finds the first token of `-` and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's step through the example expression `1 * 2 - 3`. The parser starts at the beginning.

- The first token matches `1` in `primary`. Consume `1`.
- Control returns to `factor`, `expr` is set to `1`. The `while` condition then matches the `*`. Consume `*`.

  - In the `while` loop, it tries to consume a `unary` next, this successfully matches `primary` `2`. Consume `2`.
  - Expression is set to `1 * 2`. No more `[*/]` to consume, loop terminates. Return this expression to `term`.
- `term` enters while loop and sees `-`. Consumed `-` (meaning the next token is `3`, not `-`)

  - Tries to consume a `factor`, which successfully matches `3` in `primary`. Consume the `3`.
  - Expression is set to `1 * 2 - 3`.

This results in the tree:

```
    -
  *   3
 1 2
```

In other words, because `term` has already consumed `1 * 2` as a `factor`, `term` will enter the `while` loop, not call `factor` again. This successfully recognizes the `-` as an operator in `term` instead of part of a `unary` expression.

Comment: could you, please, explain the flow for `1 - 2 * 3`?

Comment: I got it when more precedence operation comes first in the statement but when it goes the second I don't see the same logic works correctly in that case because the first token will become "primary" anyways and woun't take into account `- 2` part

Comment: @Herrgott Sure. Starting with the `1` (unary) in `1 - 2 * 3`, control returns to `term` because the next token is a `-`. The `while` loop then tries to parse a `factor`, which eventually returns `2 * 3`.

Answer (score 1):

> unary() function which will iterate through tokens

No, it doesn't. It looks only at the next input token and sees that it is not a `-`.  So it returns `primary()`.

The actual code from the page your linked in your question is:

```java
  private Expr unary() {
    if (match(BANG, MINUS)) {
      Token operator = previous();
      Expr right = unary();
      return new Expr.Unary(operator, right);
    }

    return primary();
  }
```

That function calls `match`, not `WeFoundToken`. (I'm not sure where that comes from). `match` is defined earlier on the page:

```java
  private boolean match(TokenType... types) {
    for (TokenType type : types) {
      if (check(type)) {
        advance();
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

The loop in that function (`for (TokenType type : types)`) loops over the arguments to the call, comparing each one in turn with the next input token. It never looks at any other input token.

Comment: I've tried to shorten the code from example. Sorry for misinformation